# Rails 5 Active Record has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models which both have the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with each other.

Order

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
# Has multiple related rates.
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rates
```

Rate

```
class Rate < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
```

Rate contains currency data for a given date, while order contains a deadline. I have a job that given an Order's deadline, creates and fetches all the dates between (today..deadline) - 1 year.

Job

```
def perform(order_record)  
    (all_dates << history_weeks).flatten!
        all_dates.each do |date|
          r = Rate.find_by(date: date)
          if r == nil
            r = Rate.new(date: date)
            r.save
          end

          q = r.update(orders << order_record)
        end
```

Now the thing is that for the first ever order that I create, everything runs smoothly, the associations are made properly so that I can access the rates through `@order.rates`. 2nd and every next order that I create does not do that, despite logging the following, but only once:

`Rate Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "rates".* FROM "rates" INNER JOIN "orders_rates" ON "rates"."id" = "orders_rates"."rate_id" WHERE "orders_rates"."order_id" = ? ORDER BY "rates"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["order_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

What am I doing wrong there?

Edit:

The job is called in the orders_controller:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.user = User.find(current_user)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      GetCurrencyHistoryJob.perform_now(@order)
      format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the job

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `r.update(orders << order_record)`

The syntax I've always seen is

```
r.orders << order_record
```

You can also tidy up this

```
r = Rate.find_by(date: date)
if r == nil
  r = Rate.new(date: date)
  r.save
end
```

to

```
r = Rate.find_or_create_by(date: date)
```

Comment: `r.orders << order_record` produces exactly the same result: the first one rolls out fine, the next ones do not.